# How to connect with SSH or SFTP to a local DDEV Container?

Tags: ssh, sftp, ddev

I installed:

- Docker https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/
- Homebrew https://brew.sh/
- DDEV https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation
- Composer https://getcomposer.org/download/

I installed TYPO3 with:

```
composer create-project typo3/cms-base-distribution ddevtypo3 ^8
```

I configured DDEV with:

```
cd ddevtypo3
ddev config
```

and hit 3 times **Enter** for default-values for: project-name, docroot, project-type.

Now (nearly finished) I started DDEV with:

```
ddev start
```

Everything works fine: I become my 'Thank you for downloading TYPO3' Installwindow on my local DDEV Server ddevtypo3.ddev.local works.

---

Now I want to connect with my Coda2 to the Container. If I type `ddev ssh` in the Terminal, I come in the DDEV container, but how can I configure Coda2 to use SFTP or SSH to connect to the DDEV.

Somebody can give me the right hint?

Perhaps I have to configure SSH or SFTP for the DDEV.

---

Edit:

I want to use the SFTP Connection to just for editing files on the Container and SSH to connect with the Coda-Terminal to the Container.

Comment: Could you explain what Coda2 is? Mostly people use `ddev ssh` to get into the web container. It uses `docker exec`, not ssh, despite the naming.

Comment: I see https://panic.com/coda/ - It's just an IDE? You can certainly do code editing on the host (it's mounted into the container so changes there right away). And you can use `ddev ssh` inside its terminal. But maybe you can expand on what you want to do with it.

Comment: [Coda2](https://panic.com/coda/) is a Texteditor for remote Editing Files that also has a Terminal via SSH and DB-functionality. - I want to use SSH also for my Git-Repositories .. I think its a similar issue, but the same problem. Need to communicate with outside of the container.

Comment: In https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/414 there are a couple of ideas about going forward with actual ssh in the container (which doesn't solve ssh-to-the-container, which most people have been ok with `ddev ssh`). We don't have an actual solution at this point, other than using the Coda2 terminal to `ddev ssh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have to connect to the local Container with SSH, because I can edit the files directly local:

### In Coda2

- In the file-browser tab I can browse local (the left window).
- And in the site-window I can press at the bottom left of the earth-globe and it's also the local filesystem.

I also can commit and push to my Gitlab with the terminal. I don't need the Coda2-SSH-Connection to my Container also for publishing my work to Git.

- In the shell-tab click the drop-down of Connection and select localhost.
- Or simply use the Terminal of the MacBook

  - I also can use `ddev ssh` to connect to the container (both ways)

I realize now: that was not a good question, but I don't delete it to get others informed for this thinking errors - and the way to get all done without the way I'd tried.

And for new ddev-users, like me... ;)

Comment: Thanks - I was going down this same path (how do I sftp into a container on my local drive). Now, of course, I can see that I can access the files directly in...my local drive!